# R: Parsing ConceptNet5 syntax into Data frame

Tags: r, semantics

I have been going at this for a few hours now with `grep` and `gsub` but I feel like I am not really approaching this problem correctly.

I am using an amazing publicly available dataset [ConceptNet5](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/) which maps connection between concepts (which I found on the [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/data-for-word-hierarchies/1212#1212) community).

The data from the 'csv' file looks the following when read by a text editor:

```
/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/port/,/c/en/on_coast/]  /r/RelatedTo    /c/en/port  /c/en/on_coast  /ctx/all    0.02592754036220567 /s/site/verbosity   /e/4251f811726a5bc2d5c37636e6d9323b1d1f0d97 /d/verbosity    [[port]] is related to [[on coast]]
/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/port/,/c/en/ship_offload/]  /r/RelatedTo    /c/en/port  /c/en/ship_offload  /ctx/all    0.04264433740849372 /s/site/verbosity   /e/0756f548fdcf0f2534719cce5c19f514cc32c037 /d/verbosity    [[port]] is related to [[ships offload]]
/a/ [/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/port/,/c/en/wooden/]   /r/RelatedTo    /c/en/port  /c/en/wooden    /ctx/all    0.01010845347428868 /s/site/verbosity   /e/f95913c8a1c1263b494bdda44c12a3c50d025c8b /d/verbosity    [[port]] is related to [[wooden]]
```

With `/a/` indicating that there is an assertion with three elements to the assertion found in the `[,,]`. The `/r/` refers to 'language-independent relations', the `/c/` concept, the `/en/` English, and `/port/` and `/on_coast/`. The meaning of the first line presented here as I can best understand it is expressing the assertion that the port is related to the coast.

In order to make this data tractable in R I want to convert it into a `dataframe` which looks something like the following

```
     assertion    subject    object        lang1 lang2  
 [1] RelatedTo    port       on_coast      en    en
 [2] RelatedTo    port       ship_offload  en    en
 [3] RelatedTo    port       wooden        en    en
```

If you scroll to the right of the data there seems to be an identical representation of the assertion information. I am not sure what this is for. There is also some additional information about the source of the assertion `/s/`. I don't think I need this information.

If someone could be so kind as to point me in the right direction as to how to transform this data into an R friendly format, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the `csv` file using `read.table`, with space as a separator.  This will give you a data frame with a number of columns.  However, you can throw away every column except for the first one, since the first one contains all the information you need to build the data frame example you gave in your question.  The first column will have values looking something like this:

```
/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/port/,/c/en/on_coast/]
```

And here is the code to read in the `csv` file:

```
data <- read.table("datafile.csv",
                   header=FALSE,
                   sep= "")          # delimeter is any amount of whitespace

data <- data[, 1]                    # retain only the first column
colnames(data) <- c("rawdata")       # rename first column
```

To extract out the information you want for you final data frame, you will need to use regular expressions on the first column of data frame `data`.  Here is a regular expression to extract out the `assertion` column:

```
data$assertion <- gsub("\\/a\\/\s*\\[\\/r\\/(.*)\\/\\,", "\\1", data$rawdata)
```

This regular expression will take everything it finds in between `/a/[/r/` and `/,` and store it into the `assertion` column of the data frame.

I will leave it to you as homework to take care of the other columns.

Comment: This creates some problems because spaces seem to be randomly thrown into the data. Is there a way of reading in data without attempting to separate it into different columns?

Comment: I changed the delimeter in `read.table` to "", which means that any amount of spaces, tabs, newlines, or carriage returns will separate columns.

Comment: Don't we want a single column rather than no column? The challenge is that I think there is some text data that looks like this `/a/ [/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/port/,/c/en/wooden/] `

Comment: You never mentioned this in your original problem.  Please update the question with the exact data we need to handle, thanks.

Comment: I again updated the code to handle the whitespace problem you have.  You should really try to solve this on your own if you can, as we do not have your data set in front of us.

Comment: This will not work because of the `data[, 1] ` command since for the last row column 1 will only have `/a/` in it. I ended up setting `sep= "~"` since this character did not exist in the data set though this seems like a of system resources. After some more thought I ended up using comma separation and then reducing the wanted values from the firs three columns.